# Can we replace "Fast food" in "Fast food it is" with another noun phrase?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

I found the following dialogue:

> A: What do you want to eat for lunch?
>   
> B: How about fast food?
>   
> A: OK.**Fast food it is.**

For the non-native speakers like me, it's very difficult to catch the meaning of 'fast food it is'.  Can the subject (in this case, 'fast food') be changed in any way? For example, can we say 'OK. Baseball it is' in response to the question 'Why don't we watch baseball on TV?'

Comment: What makes you think it cannot? The structure “X it is” means something along the lines of ‘all right, that’s settled: out of the options under discussion, we’re going to go with X’. I don’t see why baseball should be any different from fast food in that sense. (I would probably not consider _fast food_ the subject here, though: _it_ is the subject. The fast food is more likely the subject complement.)

Comment: Thanks for your explanation.  What I don't understand is the structure of this phase 'X it is.' and why it means 'all right that's settled.'  I know the sentence 'It is fast food', the answer given when asked 'What did you eat tonight?'

Comment: No, if you’re asked “What _did_ you eat tonight?” (past tense), “It is fast food” is not a valid answer. “It was fast food” would be valid (though just “Fast food” would be more normal). There really isn’t anything to understand about the phrase ‘X it is’—it’s an idiom that simply just means what it means. You cannot deduce its meaning from its constituents (that’s what ‘idiom’ means), you just have to accept that as a whole, it means what it means. ‘X it is’ means something completely different from ‘it is X’, despite the fact that it’s the same words with the same syntactic function.

Comment: 'X it is [then]' is a snowclone. I'd say that it's a very productive one, as the register involved is highly colloquial. There will be some logical restrictions. 'Perfidy it is' / 'Ragamuffin it is' / 'Amphisbaena it is' would need some strange contexts. /// Note that 'Plastic it is' could mean you're agreeing to buy disposable cutlery, you're agreeing that the Ming vase might have been a poor buy, you're agreeing what next month's topic on U3A Science will be.... And that X can be plural: 'Chips it is'.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet You should write your comment up as an answer.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth My first thought for “Plastic it is” was that you were agreeing to pay by credit card.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  A snowclone is it?, what was the original then? I can easily imagine that the decision to send in the Trogan Horse, as opposed to laying siege, was announced by the phrase "perfidity it is". "[Raggamuffin](http://www.abc.net.au/news/image/7058136-3x2-700x467.jpg) it is" comes easily enough as well. And is that a [white bellied worm lizard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amphisbaena_alba)? Amphisbaena it is.

Comment: @Phil Sweet. I'm not really interested in spending a lot of time trying to find an original. You are free to, if you wish. The definition doesn't demand that an original be known.  // Like I said, strange examples.

Answer (score 2):

When A answers "***Fast food it is***", the subject of the sentence is ***it*** (i.e.'*what lunch will be*', the answer to *what?*).  So...

'Fast food ***it*** is' = 'Fast food is *what lunch will be*' = Lunch will be fast food.

***Fast food it is*** is an example of a [rhetorical inversion](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=rhetorical+inversion&oq=rhetorical+inversion&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.3666j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Notice that the OP dialogue involves agreement/concession between parties.  If you ask simply ***Why don't we watch baseball on TV?*** there is no agreement/concession involved.  In order to use the inverted rhetorical agreement/concession (!) there needs to be debate followed by agreement/concession, for example

> A:'Why don't we watch baseball on TV?'
>
> B:'Can't we watch something else for a change?'
>
> A:'But it's the final tonight...'
>
> B:'OK, baseball it is'.